# Dirichlet Problem on the Disk Using Hilbert Transform

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am trying to solve the Dirichlet problem on the disk: find a square integrable, holomorphic function *f* on the unit disk such that Re *f* has a prescribed boundary value *x* in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$, when restricted to the circle. Furthermore, show that *f* is unique up to an additive, imaginary constant.

So far I have considered the orthonormal basis $\{e_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, where each $e_n$ is defined by
\begin{align*}
e_n := (2\pi)^{-1/2}z^n \ \forall \ z \in \mathbb{T},
\end{align*}
on $L^2(\mathbb{T})$. I have shown that the operator $W \in {\bf B}(L^2(\mathbb{T}))$ defined by
\begin{align*}
We_0 = e_0, \ \ \ We_n = -ie_n, \ \ \ We_{-n} = ie_{-n} \ \forall \ \mathbb{N}
\end{align*}
is a unitary operator that maps real functions to real functions in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$.

I am not sure how to start solving the Dirichlet problem, i.e., I am not sure how to look for such a function *f* and how to use the above observations in this search.

Comment: Maybe you could try starting from this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel ?

Comment: This is not the Dirichlet problem. You can solve this problem by using the solution to the Dirichlet problem (by the Poisson integral) together with the Hilbert transform.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ be the prescribed real part of the boundary value.

Let $$a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}{b(e^{it})e^{-int}\,dt}$$ be its Fourier coefficients, $a_n \in \ell^2$ and $a_{-n}=\overline{a_n}$.

Consider a real function $h \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$, of which the Fourier coefficients are $ia_n$ for $n < 0$ and $-ia_n$ for $n > 0$, then $b+ih \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ and has no nonzero Fourier coefficients with negative indices. Denote $c_n$ for $n \geq 0$ its Fourier coefficients (with the same formula as above), $c_n \in \ell^2$.

Define then $f(z)=\sum_n{c_nz^n}$ on the unit disk. You can check that $f$ is $L^2$ and that its radial limit (in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ and a.e.) is $b+ih$.